# Internal Server Error (500) come up in redirect page when I Sign In

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, internal-server-error

## Description

I have two website deploy in my local. One is my main website build in `.NET-Core` like(`a.butter.com`),another is a website about login and register build in `.NET-Framework` like(`passport.butter.com`). Today,when I want to click `Login` in my main website `a.butter.com`, and I found sign in successfully and return to the ReturnUrl `a.butter.com`. But the page shows the error Internal Server Error (500). Can anyone help me to explain why?

## Error Message

> [Error] Connection id ""0HL2JU00MCUG0"": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).) ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).

## Error in Postman

> Message": "An error has occurred.",
>
> "ExceptionMessage": "An error occurred while performing an encryption >operation.",
> "ExceptionType": "System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out. The solution is that. The encrypt and decode is based on MachineKey in `web.config`.

`C# web.config
...
<machineKey decryption="AES" decryptionKey="223423424234234234SFSDFASGDGREGG" validation="SHA1" validationKey="436346RETEWRGSDAFASDFDSVASDFFASDDGRAGRGSFADFVAVDCSADCETREG" compatibilityMode="Framework45"/>
...`

 And I found the config in passport.butter.com is different with another. So, it come up the error. When I change the MachineKey to the same with others and solved my problem.